# Disabling "Send Outbound Messages" in Community User Profile

Tags: permissions, guest-user, critical-update

I'm working on securing my guest user for upcoming critical Salesforce updates and I have a few permissions I can't figure out how to resolve the issues. Specifically:

•   Permissionsenablenotifications
•   Permissionsemailtemplatemanagement
•   Permissionsemailadministration

I know the labels associated with these permissions, however the only one visible in the profile for the guest community user is "Send Outbound Messages" or (Permissionsenablenotifications). However, this particular option is not editable within the profile page. It is checked and cannot be unchecked. Does anyone know how I can resolve these issues? Any help provided would be appreciated.

[image: Permissionsenablenotifications]
[image: Permissionsemailtemplatemanagement]
[image: Permissionsemailadministration]

Sincerely,
J

Comment: let me guess that you are using the Guest User Access Report (GUAR). Despite this being flagged in the report; there's no way to disable this that I could find

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update backend permissions(Permissionsenablenotifications, Permissionsemailtemplatemanagement, Permissionsemailadministration) on the community profile. Use workbench to check above field values on profile and when you try to update it doesn't allow.

[image]

Thanks,